# Returning longest adjective from an array of nested adjectives

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have two arrays. One is a smaller array of environments, the other is a larger, nested array that contains a list of adjectives for each environment. The arrays correspond to one another by index. I would like to create a function that takes in the environment as an argument and returns the longest adjective that describes that environment.

The function I've created returns ONLY the longest word in the entire adjectives array, not the longest adjective unique to a given environment. 
I want to create a function called "longestAdjective" that takes in one of the environments and returns ONLY the longest adjective corresponding to that environment from the list of adjectives.

```
environmentsArray = ["Desert", "Rainforest", "Mountains", "Plains"]

adjectives = [["dry", "hot", "scorching"], ["humid", "shady", 
"wet"], ["cool", "chilly", "windy"], ["flat", "reaching", "sunny"]]

let longAdjective = (environment) => {
  let longAdj = ""
  let length = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < adjectives.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < adjectives[i].length; j++) {
    if (adjectives[i][j].length > length) {
      length = adjectives[i][j].length;
      longAdj = adjectives[i][j];
    }
  }
}

return longAdj
}
```

I don't have any error messages because I'm trying to recreate the function I've already made. I'm not sure exactly where to start.

Comment: Can you please show your attempt so far? What is your expected output? Is it `["scorching", "humid", "chilly", "reaching"]` ?

Comment: Could you please share the code of your function, @jshelper, so that we can help you to identify a problem in your approach?

Comment: Yes. If `longestAdjective("Desert")` I would expect "scorching" to be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the relevant subarray, finding the longest within that. The code you current have iterates over *all* the subarrays, which isn't what you want.

```js
const environmentsArray = ["Desert", "Rainforest", "Mountains", "Plains"];

const adjectives = [["dry", "hot", "scorching"], ["humid", "shady", 
"wet"], ["cool", "chilly", "windy"], ["flat", "reaching", "sunny"]];

const longAdjective = (environment) => {
  let longAdj = ""
  let length = 0;
  
  const envIndex = environmentsArray.indexOf(environment);

  if (envIndex === -1) {
    return;
  }

  for (const adj of adjectives[environmentsArray.indexOf(environment)]) {
    if (adj.length > length) {
      length = adj.length;
      longAdj = adj;
    }
  }

  return longAdj;
}

console.log(longAdjective('Desert'));
```

Answer (score 1):

something like that ?

```js
const environmentsArray = ["Desert", "Rainforest", "Mountains", "Plains"]
  ,   adjectives        = [ ["dry", "hot", "scorching"]
                          , ["humid", "shady", "wet"]
                          , ["cool", "chilly", "windy"]
                          , ["flat", "reaching", "sunny"]
                          ]


const LongestAdjective = environment =>
  {
  let idx = environmentsArray.findIndex(e=>e===environment)
  if (idx<0) return null
  return adjectives[idx].reduce((a,c)=>((a.length<c.length)?c:a))
  }            


console.log( 'Rainforest :', LongestAdjective('Rainforest') )       
console.log( 'Plains     :', LongestAdjective('Plains') )
```

Comment: While `reduce` absolutely works, it's probably best to work with the code OP provided.

Comment: When I read the question the OP explained that he had no idea how to proceed. Moreover, I think it's really a good thing that he can see other ways of doing

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reduce` function to get the longest adjective from the `adjectives` `array` based on the `environment` entry choosed :

```js
const environmentsArray = ['Desert', 'Rainforest', 'Mountains', 'Plains'],
  adjectives = [
    ['dry', 'hot', 'scorching'],
    ['humid', 'shady', 'wet'],
    ['cool', 'chilly', 'windy'],
    ['flat', 'reaching', 'sunny']
  ],
  longestAdjective = (env) => {
    return adjectives[environmentsArray.indexOf(env)].reduce((a, b) => {
      return a.length > b.length ? a : b
    }); /** the callback function does the filtration based on the string length of "a" (current element in the array) and "b" (the next element to check). The callback function is called for every value in the array **/
  }
console.log(longestAdjective('Desert')); /** output: "scorching" **/
```

> Learn more about [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.